# How to find voltage gradient using electrodes?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, capacitance, electromagnetic-induction

I have a capacitor, and between them I have an array of electrodes stacked orthogonal to the capacitor plates. The capacitor is running an AC current, and the electrodes are measuring voltage.

What I want to see is the voltage gradient between the capacitors, but when I take the max voltage across the array, they all have the same value.

I know that because in an AC current, the electrodes must be receiving the induced current from the changing magnetic field, but I am not sure how to take that information and find the voltage gradient of the electric field between the plates.
\begin{align*}
\nabla \times E = - \frac{\partial B}{\partial t}
\end{align*}
I think with my electrodes I am measuring,
\begin{align}
E = - \frac{d \Phi}{dt}
\end{align}
So how to do I take these values (current in V) and turn it into the Voltage Gradient?

Comment: What is the circuit arrangement that you used to measure the voltages?  Which instrument(s) did you use to measure the voltages?

Comment: See if [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268710/intuitive-explanation-for-uniform-electric-field-between-capacitor-plates) helps.